# Does backbonejs use "live binding" like canjs?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascriptmvc

I've been comparing js mvc's and noticed that a nice amount of people are bragging on the "live binding" that canjs does. Can someone explain what exactly it is and how it helps in comparison to the other popular mvc's like backbonejs, spine, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone does support **implementing** model binding, but it's not **automatic** as in some other client-side application frameworks, for example, [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org)'s data-binding through `ng-controller` or [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_binding-element-attributes-with-bindattr)'s `bindAttr`.

For some really rudimentary code to update views as a model's state changes, use `Backbone.View`'s [`events` object](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents), as in this example:

```
var ExampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'myView',

    events: {
        // using an #id selector here is also acceptable
        'change [data-attrname=name]': function(e) {
            // update the value in the model
            this.model.set('name', $(e.target).val());
        }
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
         this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        var html = _.template('<h1 data-attrname="name"><%= name %></h1>', 
                              this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Which will render the following HTML (`myView` is the div implicitly created by ExampleView):

```
<div id="myView">
    <h1 data-attrname="name"></h1>
</div>
```

This is essentially doing binding manually from the UI and wholesale (re-`render`ing the entire view) when the model changes. Backbone is intentionally designed to be less opinionated than some other frameworks, to allow you to implement things as you see fit with the addition of other libraries.

For some more sophisticated techniques on how to model bind more automatically, here are a few resources listed by their authors:

1. [Los Techies / Derek Bailey](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding)
2. [theironcook](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder)
3. [XTargets](http://xtargets.com/2011/06/11/binding-model-attributes-to-form-elements-with-backbone-js/)

Answer (score 6):

You use live binding because with CanJS, you replace all that code with:

`<h1><%= model.attr('name') %></h1>`